# build a scatter table in python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I wanted to sort items not by one of the attributes, but by two. The usual way is to sort them by one item after another, but it doesn't work properly. The reason is that, for example this table is sorted by `attr1`:

| name | attr1 | attr2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3 |
| b | 2 | 1 |

sorted by `attr2`, it will be:

| name | attr1 | attr2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 3 |

Therefore I can't see any way to sort them in a way that we can build a matrix, sorting them from low to high in 2 dimensions. But scatter plot does the exact thing. What is the procedure to do that?

Comment: What do you mean sorting by 2 values? The only way is to sort by 1 first then another next. With only 2 elements the first sort will have no effect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.